Azure CosmosDB - HttpTrigger - javascript - how to make the endpoint normally than duplicate like {partitionKeyValue} and {id}
I am following pluralsight to create - HTTP trigger, look up ID from route data
The course was a tad outdated, so does not work as expected. (example endpoint is  readable , but doesn't work in the new version)

I followed Microsoft docs and using new version to do the same
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-javascript#http-trigger-look-up-id-from-route-data-javascript
const { app, input } = require('@azure/functions');

const cosmosInput = input.cosmosDB({
    databaseName: 'ToDoItems',
    collectionName: 'Items',
    id: '{id}',
    partitionKey: '{partitionKeyValue}',
    connectionStringSetting: 'CosmosDBConnection',
});

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    route: 'todoitems/{partitionKeyValue}/{id}',
    extraInputs: [cosmosInput],
    handler: (request, context) => {
        const toDoItem = context.extraInputs.get(cosmosInput);
        if (!toDoItem) {
            return {
                status: 404,
                body: 'ToDo item not found',
            };
        } else {
            return {
                body: `Found ToDo item, Description=${toDoItem.Description}`,
            };
        }
    },
});


of course there are errors in documentation (connectionStringSetting and collectionName which should be connection and containerName)
but invocation is as below
Invoke-WebRequest  http://localhost:7071/api/todo/2/2

Aboout my Cosmos Emulator - container specified partition key as = /id
The above url does not look good to me duplicate path.
I have to use partitionkey and I have to use id. So I'm not sure how I can make the endpoint nice.
like http://localhost:7071/api/todo/2
Please advice

As mentioned in the MSDOC, it is mandatory to pass the partition key, in case of partitioned containers.

When the collection is partitioned, lookup operations must also specify the partition key value.


To avoid using duplicate values for Id and Partition Key in the route, follow below steps:

Define some random value in the partitionkey manually while creating the container in portal.



Define the value to the partitionkey in the Json file which you upload to the container.

Example:

My Json file:

{
    "id":"1",
    "key":"2",
    "Description":"Hello World"
}  


Upload the file to the Cosmos Container.

This generates the new item with id and key as defined in the uploaded Json file.

Code Snippet:
const { app, input } = require('@azure/functions');

const cosmosInput = input.cosmosDB({
    databaseName: 'db1',
    containerName: 'container1',
    id: '{id}',
    partitionKey: '{partitionKeyValue}',
    connection: 'CosmosDBConnection'
});

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    route: 'Items/{partitionKeyValue}/{id}',
    extraInputs: [cosmosInput],
    handler: (request, context) => {
        const toDoItem = context.extraInputs.get(cosmosInput);
        if (!toDoItem) {
            return {
                status: 404,
                body: 'Item not found',
            };
        } else {
            return {
                body: `Found Item, Description=${toDoItem.Description}`,
            };
        }
    },
});

Console Response:
[2024-04-22T11:56:37.019Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        httpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/Items/{partitionKeyValue}/{id}

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-04-22T11:56:59.194Z] Executing 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=d8fdefe9-5643-4c5e-b32d-44f353e75fd2)
[2024-04-22T11:57:03.143Z] Executed 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=d8fdefe9-5643-4c5e-b32d-44f353e75fd2, Duration=4028ms)

Output:


If I create a function and give it to users, why do they need to know partition number key ? say I want stock price of APPLE. why parition key is required ?

As I mentioned in the answer, it is mandatory to specify the partition key value in the function URL, because we are using partitioned container. In the example you mentioned, the partition key value can be any property like symbol or company, further it can be used in the query to fetch the results.
